# Replace everything but forward slash or digits

Tags: c#, .net

I'm looking for regular expression to replace all characters except forward slashes or digits with an empty string.

I have the following which strips everything but digits:

```
Regex.Replace(time, "[^0-9]", "");
```

Comment: Okay, so you're nearly there already - what difficulty did you have in modifying your regex? Do you understand how the existing regex works? What changes have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

```
Regex.Replace(time, "[^0-9/]", "");
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Regex.Replace(time, "[^0-9|/]", "");
```

Comment: Why the `|`? It's already within a set, so there's no need for alternation as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `[^0-9/]` is the right pattern.

```
[^0-9/]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/loXHHxer9zvYm_LA)